# How to call div that has a certain class, from a certain url using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to bring a div that has a class ('i-today') from a certain URL to the homepage of my website. is there a way to do this with javascript?

This may sound stupid but the reason I am trying to do this is because i just need the contents of the current day from a calendar, but I have no idea how  to change the query to just show the contents of the current date(which has the class 'i-today'). so instead I just want bring it from the already rendered page.

Comment: Could you please post some code? It is difficult to understand what your exact requirement is

Comment: you'd have to download the content of the entire page via AJAX, then parse the HTML to get the part you need. You can't just download a snippet of a document via HTTP. Even then, if this calendar page is not your site, you might encounter CORS issues - you might have to do the download in your server-side code first and then embed it into your page that way. Or, investigate if this site has an API or similar means to return the event data, which you can then display. Or maybe, just like Twitter etc, they provide a documented way to embed their content in your page.

Comment: However...you mention some sort of "query". What query is this? A SQL query? URL querystring? API call? Maybe it _can_ be changed to get the current date information only, and maybe in a better format. I say maybe because we have no idea what this query is or how it works, because you didn't provide any details. Clearly if you can get just the data you want, that would be preferable. Maybe explain to us what this query is all about and post some relevant code and data sample, and we could help you fix/change it.

Comment: If you have control over the other page, you could give each day an id and then just target that element with an ajax request

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ok so I'm using this korean forum board plugin called 'mangboard' on my wordpress site. what I meant by query is that I do have access to the code so if i was smart enough i'm sure i could make the calendar call only the current days content, but it's just way too difficult for me to do that.
if it helps, this is the calendar page 
http://bhswc.kr/?page_id=671

and this is the page i want to call in just the current date's content
http://bhswc.kr/?page_id=30

I would really like to show some example code but tbh i don't even know where to start.